# Какие ошибки есть в тексте стихотворения?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Стихотворение Ивана Бездомного (апокриф)

Непонятно, что дальше.
Я как сивуч реву.
Не, в натуре, без фальши -
снова, снова плыву!

Чую, хвост мой поджатый
очень сильно замёрз...
"Эй, вагоновожатый! 
Впереди Берлиоз!"...

Ох как глюкнуло резко!
Что за дичь, что за дичь?!...
Под рукою железка -
то ли Пётр, то ль Ильич.

Хороша аватара! -
ОтвечАю!... Потом
проплывает отара.
Не хочу - за скотом.

Мне сейчас бы на печку,
чтоб - глинтвейн, чтобы - стих!
Под рукою овечка...
Нету мест для двоих?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грамматических ошибок не видно. Смысл не шибко ясен. Можно придраться к сравнительному обороту "как сивуч", который должен бы выделяться запятыми,  но не факт, текст рифмованный всё-таки, пунктуация допустима авторская. Можно трактовать не как сравнительный оборот, а как обстоятельство образа действия. "Глюкнуло" - окказионализм? Приходилось слышать "глюканýло", "заглючило" в разговорной речи айтишников, со значением загадочно нештатного срабатывания программы или матчасти компьютера. Глагольных форм от наркоманского "глюк" (галлюцинация) не встречал, там больше в ходу аналитические формы "поймать, словить глюк" либо глаголы от других основ - торкнуло, вставило, доставило, вштырило, пропёрло, пробило на глюки... Хотя любая феня штука быстроизменчивая, мне вот интересно, это самопридуманное слово или употребляемое в каких-то группах?

Comment: Слово самопридуманное. А смысл стиха туманен, поскольку он написан от лица безумного И.Бездомного.) А вот "то ли, то лЬ" - допустимо?

Comment: Теоретически от лица безумного Бездомного, который и сам признавал, что стихи его плохи, допустимо всё ). 
Редукция гласных в поэтическом тексте вещь обычная, а что звучит немного непривычно, так после "глюкнуло" это семечки ).

Comment: Спасибо, mueller!

Answer (score 1):

Если на минуту стать занудой, можно увидеть синтаксический провал, и не только.

Непонятно, что (**тире**) дальше. Я (**запятая**, он же не мерин) как сивуч реву. Не (надо: **Не-а**, **Не** как частица не употребляется отдельно. Здесь — в значении **Нет** или **точно**), в натуре, без фальши - (**д.б. тире**) снова, снова плыву! (Знак **!** не логичен).

Чую, хвост мой поджатый очень сильно замёрз... (Многоточие? Разве фраза не окончена? Хотя, если бы не Берлиоз, про копыта поведал бы). "Эй, вагоновожатый! Впереди (**тире**) Берлиоз!"...

Ох как (**Эх, как бы дожить бы** ничем не хуже выглядит: **запятая**) 
глюкнуло резко! Что за дичь, что за дичь?!... (Многоточие. Не **часто** ли?) Под рукою железка - (не чёрточка, **тире**) то ли Пётр, то ль Ильич.

Хороша аватара! - (не чёрточка, точно) Отвечаю!... (Многоточие. **Часто**.) Потом проплывает отара. Не хочу - (не чёрточка, **тире**) за скотом.

Мне сейчас бы на печку, чтоб - глинтвейн, чтобы - (не чёрточка, **тире**) стих! Под рукою овечка... (Многоточие. **Это — любовь**.) Нету мест для двоих?

Comment: А я чёрточки в качестве тире ставлю. Не знаю даже, где это настоящее тире у меня на клаве.) Многоточие, по авторской задумке, должно показать разорванность мышления больного Ивана, перескакивание с темы на тему. Спасибо, shampar!

Comment: Все символы на клавиатуре никак не поместились бы. Они — в Таблице символов, которую можно найти в Стандартных программах и вывести ярлык на Рабочий стол.